# Just use a sub-directory of a working copy

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Say I recursively checkout a folder A which has sub-folders B, C and D. Then later decide I only really wanted to work on C so I wish I had just checked out C on its own.

In SVN 1.6, folder C has its own ".svn" folder, so I could just move C somewhere else and then delete the old working copy, and C would still be a self-contained working copy on its own.

is there any way to achieve the same thing in 1.7 or later?

Comment: No there isn't. But why don't you simply make another checkout?

Comment: The problem was that there have been changes both to my working copy of C and to the repo, and a massive new project had been added into A so I didn't want to update the whole thing or checkout a new copy of C because my connection to the server is quite slow. I ended up just updating C, the committing, and then having to do a new checkout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've needed this I just temporarily make a copy the directory outside the SVN checked out folder structure, roll back all changes to the whole checkout, then past my copied folder back.

This way all changes to B and D were erased, but the ones for C can be committed separately.

EDIT: To clarify, this works if your changes haven't been committed yet. If that's not the case, either roll back your local changes before copying the temp copy of C back, or checkout another copy from your repository and do this.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense - I was just wondering if there was a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, why you just don't commit (for **existing WC-tree** A/C) **only** C folder?

In this case (changes in C and somewhere else in WC) you get revision with C-related changes only and still modified Working Copy.

CLI-version of such commit `svn ci -m "Commit message" С/` (TBT!), according to `svn help commit`

> usage: commit [PATH...]

(note PATH part)

For GUI-way of TortoiseSVN you jest select `TortoiseSVN` - `Commit` not for root of your Working Copy, but for single folder with changes